# Remove PHP tags from the beginning and end of a string

Tags: php, string

How can I remove the `<?php` and `<?` tags from the beginning of a string and the `?>` tag from the end?

I cannot use `str_replace`, as these tags may be used in other places in the string to start and stop PHP sections - I just want to remove them from the beginning and the end.

Also, whitespace before/after these tags should be ignored - so if the string starts with     `<?php`, the `<?php` section should still be removed.

Comment: @AleksG Nice thought, but I'm not too sure of what regex I would need

Comment: You want to remove the PHP tags using PHP?

Comment: Remove the PHP tags from a string, but only at the beginning and end of a string

Comment: don't forget that: (1) PHP can have multiple `<?php` and `?>` tags throughout a program, (2) it can also have `<?` and `<?=`, depending on server config (or even `<%`, though that's rare), and (3) the `<?php and `?>` do not necessarily have to be at the start and end of the program; in fact, the closing `?>` is entirely optional if there's no other markup after it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to use `preg_replace`:

```
$result = $preg_replace('/(\s*)<\?(php)?\s+(.+)\?>(\s*)$/','${1}${3}${4}', $input);
```

Note that this will only strip tags `<?`, `<?php` and `?>` - in the beginning and end of the input respectively (optionally preceded by whitespace).  Depending on your need, you'll need to modify the regex.

Comment: You will probably want to make leading and trailing white space optional with `\s*` instead of `\s+` and include the `p` inside of the `<\?(php)?`